# Git выдает ошибку связанную с SSL

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push

Столкнулся с проблемой, при пуше выдает ошибку связанную с SSL:
[image: fatal: unable to access]

fatal: unable to access https://github.com/____: error:1407742E:SSL rountines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsc1 alert protocol version

Пробовал то что описано [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458822/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-ssl-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B0) - не помогло. Как быть?

Comment: Пожалуйста: 1. Исправьте название вопроса, чтобы оно было информативным. 2. Замените картинку текстом (а то никто не сможет найти ваш вопрос по аналогичной проблеме).

Comment: судя [по](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48944875/4827341), у вас слишком старая версия программы *git*.

Comment: у меня windows 10, клиент git последний, пробовал отключать проверку SSL сертификата, добавлять [http]
sslVersion = tlsv1.0
sslVersion = tlsv1.1
sslVersion = tlsv1.2

Comment: ничего не помогло все равно продолжает возвращаться ошибка fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/drno-reg/um_open.git/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Comment: Действительно, была не обновленная версия гита. Причем апдейт не помог. Пришлось все сносить, и ставить завно. Спасибо за подсказку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Бала проблема с неактуальной версией гита. Полное удаление, и установка последней весрии решили проблему.